# Get an array from a response in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have an operation like the following code:

```
$t = response()->json($response);
```

When I return $t, the following response is displayed in my browser:

```
{"orderId":183,"redirectUrl":"https:\/\/sandbox.domian.com\/tg\/start\/1518"}
```

How can I get the redirectUrl from this response?
I tried this following codes but got an error:

```
return $t->redirectUrl;

return json_decode($t)['redirectUrl'];
```

> Error: Undefined property: Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse::$redirectUrl

Comment: You want to use `json_decode` which'll take your JSON string and return an object (or an array, see 2nd parameter) https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

Comment: Sorry ,I put incorrect here, I have tried `json_decode`, a null response is displayed

Comment: Try `json_decode($t, true)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `json_decode` and set the 2nd parameter to `true` if you want the result as an array. If you don't set the 2nd parameter, `json_decode` will likely return an object of type `StdClass` in which you can access the properties with `$obj->property` syntax.

http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/a6c62c9dbe7d343124648d18f4cb40e828634350

```
<?php

$json = '{"orderId":183,"redirectUrl":"https:\/\/sandbox.domian.com\/tg\/start\/1518"}';

// Notice the 2nd parameter - https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php#refsect1-function.json-decode-parameters

echo "Via array: " . json_decode($json, true)['redirectUrl'];

// Or

echo "\nVia object: " . json_decode($json)->redirectUrl;
```